# GD.SE's Winter GameJam - How should we choose the theme?

Tags: discussion, gamejam-2014-winter

It's almost time for our second gamejam, and this question here is quite important.

**How should we choose the jam's theme?**

I will post some sample answers to start with. If you have a better idea, post it as an answer. Upvote the answers you like, downvote those that you do not like. Pretty simple!

Remember, we also have a chatroom dedicated to the GD.SE GameJams, so drop by if you feel that there's a need to discuss this or some other matter further.
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10960/gdse-gamejam

Comment: Accepted answer "We build up a list of possible themes that were voted by the community, and use a computer program to pick one at random, like we did for the first jam." on 8 Jan 2014.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We build up a list of possible themes that were voted by the community, and use a computer program to pick one at random, like we did for the first jam.

Answer (score 1):

We choose a single user from the community (based on reputation or gamedev experience?) to come up with a theme. That particular user will also not be allowed to participate in the jam.

Comment: I'm willing to be that user. MUHAHAHHA

Comment: As would I, since I have no particular desire to actually make a game for the jam.

Comment: b-b-but the democracy :v

Comment: Picking randomly isn't exactly democratic either ;) I think you're just afraid of the horrible horrible theme I'd concoct.

Comment: @JoshPetrie Now that it's been decided that a theme will be picked randomly, your horrible horrible theme should go into the list from which the computer program will select.  It should go into that list at least three or four times, I reckon!  :)

Comment: What if Byte or Josh picked one of the top-rated user-submitted themes?