# The 2014 GDSE Winter Game Jam

Tags: discussion, gamejam-2014-winter

## The jam has ended!

And by the number of votes, John McDonald is the winner! Congratulations to everyone who participated in the jam! See you next time, sometime during late Spring.

> Please review all posted answers and upvote the games that you like!
> Voting will end on Sunday, the 9th of February.
>
> **Note:** We have extended the jam's duration by a day, due to timezone issues.
>
> We've decided that the winter GameJam will take place between *Jan 31
> 5 PM* and *Feb 3 5PM UTC time*.
>
> ### The Jam has started. Post your games as answers to this question. [**Submission deadline for your timezone**](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=GDSE+Game+Jam+End&iso=20140203T17)
>
> ## The Theme is "[Time is Broken](http://www.randomresult.com/ticket.php?t=5230E372Y)"
>
> ---
>
> The rules
> --------- Mostly similar to those used in the previous jam, with a couple of differences.
>
> - Participants are allowed to write games for any platform.
> - All publicly available libraries and middleware are allowed.    All publicly available creation tools (e.g. Photoshop or 3DS Max) are
>   allowed.
> - The entrant is allowed use any premade assets as long as    they're freely available on the web and the licenses allow them to be    used
>   in an open source project (e.g. opengameart.org).
> - Assets created by the entrant during the game jam may also be used.
> - The forming of teams is not allowed.
> - Each entrant may ask questions on the main    gamedev.stackexchange site, as long as the questions are on-topic as    per normal site
>   rules. Alternatively, the chatroom may also be used.
> - Each entrant must release their game as open source after attaching a    license of their choice.
>
> The two voting questions that I have opened have been answered:
>
> - [Participants are free to write games that are not web based if they so desire.](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1429/gd-ses-winter-gamejam-should-we-accept-non-web-games-too)
> - [The theme will be selected at random, from a list of possible themes, by a computer program](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1424/gd-ses-winter-gamejam-how-should-we-choose-the-theme).

Comment: Just to note my concerns for next time: The start/end times for North America start ~10am on Friday (a work day), and end at ~10am on Sunday. Consider expanding the range to cover the weekend for all time zones.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tgcif.jpg

Comment: This question has been closed to prevent new answers (submissions) from being posted after the deadline.

Comment: Congrats to everyone that finished!

Comment: Locked for posterity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Out of Time

[Play Now](http://timeisnow.jcpmcdonald.com/index.html)  *works best in Chrome (CraftyJS may throw an exception in FF, sorry)

Arrow keys or WSAD to move. No other controls. Sound isn't *required*, but it gives you audio queues and is really helpful.

I don't want to say too much else because you need to figure it out yourself.

### Source

[BitBucket Mercurial Repository](https://bitbucket.org/jcpmcdonald/out-of-time/src)

Made using [CraftyJS](http://craftyjs.com/), [Tiled Map Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org/), [Tiled Map Builder for CraftyJS](https://github.com/Kibo/TiledMapBuilder), and all sorts of art from [OpenGameArt.org](http://opengameart.org):

- [Mountain Terrain](http://opengameart.org/content/2d-lost-garden-zelda-style-tiles-resized-to-32x32-with-additions)
- [Town & Other Terrain Features](http://opengameart.org/content/lots-of-hyptosis-tiles-organized)
- [Heroine](http://opengameart.org/content/lpc-2-characters)
- [Heroine Hair](http://lpc.opengameart.org/static/lpc-style-guide/assets.html)
- [Skeleton](http://opengameart.org/content/lpc-skeleton)
- [Clock Sound](http://opengameart.org/content/ticking-clock-0)

Gear pickups were replaced post-jam by a friend of mine: Landon Deren.
The gear pickup sound was created using [as3sfxr](http://www.superflashbros.net/as3sfxr/)

I created two original pieces: The "bones" sound, and the "wake up" sound.

Comment: It doesn't appear to work 100% correctly in IE 10 either; I assume that's expected (because, you know, it's IE)?

Comment: Is there a way to restart without refreshing the page? The game took a good 15 seconds to load and I just learned that skeletons don't like hugs. (Nothing happens after "YOU ARE DEAD".)

Comment: @JoshPetrie, Yeah... Sounds about right, and sorry about that

Comment: @Anko, I was planning to have a way to reset the game, but as of right now, the only thing you can do is press F5

Comment: Makes it more important to stay alive, eh?

Comment: It's called "hardcore mode," it's a feature! (Works in Safari, by the way, a bit jittery at the start but otherwise fine, I think.)

Answer (score 4):

## Time Is Broken

*I didn't have enough time to get it working, so I did not bother with a proper title.*

Here it is, just like how I didn't plan it. Too little time, and experience as this was my first jam, but I'm still proud of it. Scriptable entities and everything!

So it has a time thingie. It might not be apparant, but the glitch happening every 30 seconds is why time is broken in this game. Therefore it is completly valid entry! It does not work at all as I intended, but at least it has something related to time being broken.

While I acknowledge it is a really bad game, I still hope it is not the worst in the jam. `;)` Anyway, I still had fun creating it and I will participate in upcoming jams.

### Download and sources

Sources are available on [github](https://github.com/Lazzu/GD.SE-2014-Winter-GameJam), and you can download the debug build from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27198869/TimeIsBroken.zip).

### How to play

Arrow keys move, space bar shoots. Nothing else in there.

### Technical details

I used C# and OpenTK, and developed it under Linux. It should work on any platform with mono or .NET 4.0 installed. No other libraries used. I wrote the ECS engine and sprite renderer myself. If you wish to have more information about anything in the code, please ask me in the GD.SE chat.

All textures used in the game are from [OpenGameArt.Org](http://opengameart.org/). Thanks for releasing such great resources!

I release all **source code** included in the git repository under MIT licence.

Comment: Nice work Lasse. It's certainly related to time being broken.

Answer (score 3):

## Pew Pew - In the broken time

This is a game I began to work on for full some days ago. Now its ready with a little storyline about the time is broken. Hope you enjoy it. Controls: the arrow keys and clicking on button.

Game: https://www.mediafire.com/?w5ty1d3q233k0u0

Source: https://www.mediafire.com/?mhmje9za4o6scje

I have made all the resources by myself.
Git publish is coming soon, but right now I have some problems with pushing to GitHub

I'm using Eclipse Public License v1.0

Comment: Crashed in the middle of a battle :(. At version 0.0.3, I can't wait to see what version 1.0.0 will look like!

Comment: @Byte56 I don't know why. It is not happening on my pc. Is it reproducing?

Comment: Yeah, just click away from the game window, then click the game window again to give it focus. Crashes every time.

Comment: @Byte56 Weird. I tested it out right now, but no crash when i defocused and focused the window

Comment: Ah, appears to only happen when on a different monitor than the main monitor in a multi-monitor setup.

Comment: This is neat. I upvoted it so in return at least work more on it. It can become quite awesome with more polish work :)

Comment: @AlexM. :D Finally something useful that I have made. This is just 0.0.3 version so more is coming. :D

Answer (score 0):

## Broken Time

A very quick game created on iOS. To play the game, open Xcode and run the app on your device. If you would like to change the way the game is controlled, change the 'preferredInput' variable in GameViewController.m (0 = tilt, 1 = dpad, 2 = external keyboard)

### Source

https://github.com/javadog36/Broken-Time

### Credits

- Platformer Art - Kenney (kenney.nl)
- Town Music - CynicMusic (cynicmusic.com)
- Battle Music - CynicMusic (cynicmusic.com)
- Raygun Sound - Apollo Music (apollo-music.de)
- Spider Sounds - Ogrebane (opengameart.com)

Comment: Hah, those are quite a lot of requirements (Mac OS X, Xcode, a developer's license...). Could you please show us a gameplay video instead? Not a lot of people would be able to play your game I believe, and it would be a pity to not get voted if it's good.

Comment: @AlexM. I don't think you need a developer's license to just run the app on a device. In any case, I'll try to put together a video later

Comment: You do. You can run it on the *simulator*, but not an actual device (plus you need to provision the device, which many people may not want to do for their carry phone if that's all they have).

Comment: @JoshPetrie Ah. Well it should work on the simulator if you enable the dpad. I'll put together a video later.

Comment: So I still need to go buy a Mac, or buy a copy of OSX to run in a VM?

Comment: @MickLH Yes, but as a response, I would need to buy a Windows computer to run most other games. We **were** allowed to create non-web games in this contest ;)

Comment: @javadog36 non sense, you can always use wine (or it's equivalent for mac!)

Comment: @Ali.S I've always found that wine doesn't work too well

Comment: @javadog36 I'm still looking forward for the video. `:)` BTW There are no windows-only games submitted. My game runs on any platform that can run mono (including mac), joapet's game is using java and I was able to run it on my linux machine, and John's game is web-based which runs on any html5-enabled platform. I also got Mick's engine to build on my linux machine, though I did not get it to run properly. But that is most likely because of for some reason I can not use GL3 contexts on this laptop even if there is support for it.

Comment: @Lasse If I do make a video, it may not be for awhile (sorry). My schedule has filled up rather quickly, and I'm not going to have the time to make one anytime soon :/

Answer (score 0):

### Find the game

Here's the engine half finished, the game is to figure out how to play it and have fun, this counts "time" and "broken" right? ;)

Source: https://github.com/micklh/MagicWorks

(I'm joking, although please do post "High Scores" if anyone manages to play it :P)

Comment: could you please also upload a binary?

Comment: I believe it is part of the game to find (build) the binary