# Ideas for the 2014 Spring GameJam

Tags: discussion

We'll hold the Spring GameJam soon enough (in a month or so, starting today, 3 March 2014). Drop all of your ideas for the new GameJam as answers here. Based on a combination of votes and relevance of comments under each answer, we'll make a list of stuff and then a poll, for everyone to vote to choose the final direction the jam will take.

The old jam format (poll to choose themes and so on) will be used as a fallback solution.

Answer (score 4):

Right now, in order to participate, users need reputation. This requires new users to build up some rep if they want to participate. Advertising the jam is a great idea to gain new users, but if the rep requirement will immediately throw them off, we'll not be getting anywhere.

My suggestion: we host the jam externally. We do the submissions and voting there. This way, anyone can participate, regardless of the reputation they have here. Unless there are better options, I could host the jam myself.

Comment: I have a bad feeling about hosting it externally. I'm all for trying it to see what happens, though.

Comment: Voting for theme (if we do that again) should at least be external. So we can use a system that hides vote counts. Not only to ensure we don't have run-away leaders but so that people don't know what the theme will be until then vote counts are revealed.

Comment: Is the goal of the gamejam to find new users or to have fun with the current users?

Comment: Having fun with the same 3 users everytime gets boring. By opening up to the world we will also get to see more exciting stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to see as many and as nice games as possible; I think that's the best to get out of a jam. I was thinking that allowing the participants to decide what their games should be about is the best way to achieve this. Removing the specific theme will indeed nullify the imagination exercise, but in turn it will allow people to come up with a great idea themselves, which may be better than anything pertaining to the theme.

So, the next theme should be: "Let's make a game."

Comment: While I don't know if this should always be the case I'm open to doing it themeless once in a while.

Answer (score -1):

I'm very iffy about installing programs on my computer and I think this gives browser-based games an unfair advantage. (The only game I played from the previous [game-jam](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/the-2014-gdse-winter-game-jam?rq=1) was John's)

To counter this advantage, I would like to propose that submissions must include a short gameplay video.

Comment: Since [animated images can be embedded directly into SE posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115266/211068), I propose submitting those instead of (only) hosting actual videos. Short instructions can be provided for possible tools to use.

Comment: Games are meant to be played, not watched. I don't think this is really helping to solve the issue you describe.